# Runtime Error [Android Studio] Linphone Project

Tags: java, android, listview, runtime-error, linphone

I build the project successfully but when I run the project on emulator I get this error on screen.

`Unfortunately Linphone has stop working!`

While the logcat displays the runtime errors

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
{org.linphone/org.linphone.LinphoneActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #60:
 Error inflating class org.linphone.ui.Numpad at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
```

Please do help me solve this out. I will totally appreciate!

Comment: what?`Unfortunately Linphone has not stop working`??

Comment: No i'm very sorry. Unfortunately Linphone has stop working! Then the app will shut down.

Comment: i think you need to add more stack trace.did you see a line start with `caused by`

Comment: plz remove this code comments and add your full stracktrace to the question by editing it